# Python naming convention for setter method name without args

Tags: python, naming, conventions

I have been writing python code with classes that will have a method called something like:

```
def set_log_paths(self):
```

The thing is, this method doesn't take an argument, it determines what some values should be based on other values of self. Is it inappropriate to use the word "set" in this case? I ask because it isn't a direct getter or a setter as one would use in a language with private members.

Is there a common conventional word to use in my method name?

Comment: Meta Question: Is there a better place to ask these conventions questions? I'm worried about being downvoted for opinion questions. The answer to this question could be "There is no convention", but that isn't really an opinion.

Comment: For me at least such cases indicate a potential [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Why `set_log_paths` isn't executed in the constructor? If that's because some values are set later, perhaps this should be a part of some other function? As a client of your class I'd probably have problems with guessing that I need to call this method. Just trying to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @BradFallon, Meta-Meta-Question have you asked that question on Meta?

Comment: Suppose he is doing several steps  in the `__init__`, and then groups the steps in function calls from there to improve readability (with good readable function names of course). I don't see a problem then. As for the `set` word there are alternatives like `setup` or `configure`. Besides, If it  is what the method does...and setters and getters are not that common (by that name) in Python because of properties, so even a client code user should suspect it is not a traditional setter but a more sophisticated action. And the plural also helps that hint. This is debatable of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you don't pass any values, and instead, compute the value at the moment the method is called, based on current values, it is reasonable that the verb describing the action be "update" - therefore `update_log_paths()`.

Just double check you really need this design, and what are the chances of you/other users of your class forgetting calling these "update" methods.

Python's introspection easily allows adopting some elements from "[reactive programing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)", which could be used to trigger these updater methods when the values they depend upon are changed.

One optimal choice for such an architecture would be a descriptor for your properties that upon having `__set__` called would check a class-level registry to "see" if events should be triggered, and then one decorator that would enable you to list the attributes that would trigger it. A base class with a proper `__init_subclass__` method could set everything up.

Let's suppose you will have the "base properties" on your class as annotated attributes in the class body - the descritptor, decorator and base-class code for this to work could be something along:

```
from functools import wraps
from collections import ChainMap

class EventDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, name, default):
        self.name = name
        self.default = default
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name] if self.name in instance.__dict__ else self.default
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
        triggers = instance._post_change_registry.get(self.name, [])
        for trigger in triggers:
            getattr(instance, trigger)()


def triggered_by(*args):
    def decorator(func):
        func._triggered_by = args
        return func
    return decorator


class EventPropertyMixin:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kw):
        super.__init_subclass__(**kw)
        for property_name, type_ in cls.__annotations__.items():
            if not hasattr(cls, property_name):
                raise TypeError("Properties without default values not supported in this example code")
            # It would also be trivial to implement runtime type-checking in this point (and on the descriptor code)
            setattr(cls, property_name, EventDescriptor(property_name, getattr(cls, property_name)))
        # collects all registries in ancestor-classes, preserving order:
        post_change_registry = ChainMap()
        for ancestor in cls.__mro__[:0:-1]:
            if hasattr(ancestor, "_post_change_registry"):
                post_change_registry = post_change_registy.new_child(ancestor._post_change_registry)
        post_change_registry = post_change_registry.new_child({})
        for method_name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
            if callable(method) and hasattr(method, "_triggered_by"):
                for property_name in method._triggered_by:
                    triggers = post_change_registry.setdefault(property_name, [])
                    if method_name not in triggers:
                        triggers.append(method_name)
        cls._post_change_registry = post_change_registry


class Test(EventPropertyMixin):
    path1: str = ""
    path2: str = ""

    @triggered_by("path1", "path2")
    def update_log_paths(self):
        self.log_paths = self.path1 + self.path2
```

And let's this working:

```
In [2]: t = Test()                                                                                       

In [3]: t.path1 = "/tmp"                                                                                 

In [4]: t.path2 = "/inner"                                                                               

In [5]: t.log_paths                                                                                      
Out[5]: '/tmp/inner'
```

So, this is complicated code, but code that usually would lie inside a framework, or in base utility libraries - with these 50 lines of code, you could be using Python to work *for* you, and have it call the updating methods, so their name won't matter at all! :-)
(ok, this code is way overkill for the question asked - but I was in a mood to produce something like this before sleeping tonight - disclaimer: I had not tested the inheritance-related corner cases covered in here)